# Simulator on xcode show only a part of iPhone

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, vmware

I'm using El Capitan on VMWare and everything works fine. 
I have a problem with the Xcode(version 7.3) simulator which is only showing part of the iPhone. I've tried to "rescale" the window but it remains same size and it's a simple application so i don't have apply auto-layout.

[image]

Comment: quit the simulator, restart it

Comment: Try selecting Window > Physical Size.

Comment: try using a smaller phone. e.g Iphone SE

Answer (score 1):

Hit Command + 1 to display the phone in actual size helps when developing on small screens, if not able to press you can find it under hardware in top menu for simulator

if you are using vmware in this case try to make the vmware screen be full screen or in preferences make dock smaller

Comment: vmware is already on full screen and the phone is already on actual size.